# apply validators.domain function on list of values in pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to check if specific domains are valid within my pandas dataframe this is a sample df:

```
   Name          Domains 
dornerworks   'dornerworks.com, iot.dornerworks.cloud'
hebcoinc      'hebcoinc.com, .hepcoinc.com'
mega-tech     'mega-tech.com'
```

And the validator:

```
new_df = old_df[old_df['Domain'].apply(lambda x: print(validators.domain(str(x))) == True)]
```

This works fine for rows that only have one domain in them and they evaluate as `True` and stay in the dataframe, however for rows with multiple domains in them it throws this error:

`ValidationFailure(func=domain, args={'value': 'hebcoinc.com, .hepcoinc.com'})`

I have a feeling its because `validators.domain(str(x))` cant iterate across rows with multiple values, how would I apply `(validators.domain(str(x))` to every value in a column if it has more than one?

I've tried doing:

`new_df = old_df[old_df['Domain'].apply(lambda x: validators.domain(str(v) for v in x) is True)]`

But I get:

`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

This is a link to the package source its a bit [sparse](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/validators/domain.html#domain)

Comment: not clear what you want but guessing this: `df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(x.Name),axis=1).drop('Name',1).values]`

Comment: `validators.domain(x)` tests whether a domain is valid or not, it works fine for single value rows, but not with ones that have more than one domain within the row. The documentation is `validators.domain.domain(value)` (as per the link) however when value is **multiple** values it fails, I'm trying to get it to apply to every value in the row, does that make sense? So `'dornerworks.com, iot.dornerworks.cloud'` will fail, but `dornerworks.com` wont, not because it's a valid domain or not, but because it can only take one input at time.